# AddWebAllowedObject is not working when .Net Native Tool Chain is Enabled

Tags: xamarin, webview, uwp

I have created UWP app which has a webview embedded in it. The webview is loaded with URL of a web app.
The web app has a JavaScript object added to the window object.
example:window.html_communicator

The web app uses this html_communicator object and calls certain methods on it to invoke callbacks on the UWP application.

for example, there can be a method defined on html_communicator called onLocationSelect and the web app will call this method upon some user interaction.
The UWP app registers to the methods by calling addWebAllowedObject on the WebView.

The callbacks are working fine when I disabled .Net Native Tool Chain.
But these callbacks are not working fine when .Net Natvie Tool Chain is enabled.

Below is a javascript code snippet that calls the bridge method on button click.

```
var html_communicator = html_communicator || {};
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("locationSelect")
        .addEventListener("click", () => {
            if (html_communicator && html_communicator.onLocationSelect) {
                document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = `Successfully called bridge method:                             Button clicked at ${new Date()}`;
            sumorea_app.onLocationSelect();
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = `Failed to call bridge method: Button clicked at ${new Date()}`;
        }
    })
    }
```

[image: Webview adding runtime component]

[image: RunTime Component]

Comment: Please refer document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview?view=winrt-20348#accessing-the-windows-runtime-in-webview), the Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) for trusted content must be added to the allowlist in the ApplicationContentUriRules of the app in Package.appxmanifest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The callbacks are working fine when I disabled .Net Native Tool Chain. But these callbacks are not working fine when .Net Natvie Tool Chain is enabled.

Please refer to webview official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview?view=winrt-20348#accessing-the-windows-runtime-in-webview), *In addition, trusted JavaScript content in WebView can be allowed to directly access Windows RuntimeAPI. This provides powerful native capabilities for web apps hosted in WebView. To enable this feature, the Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) for trusted content must be added to the allowlist in the ApplicationContentUriRules of the app in Package.appxmanifest, with WindowsRuntimeAccess specifically set to "all".*

For Xamarin solution, you need check if has add above allowlist for UWP project.

Comment: Thanks for response, 
As per your comments, WindowsRuntimeAccess was modified to "all".
After that got exceptions in the time of loading of webview. 
Unhandled exception at 0x756C46D2 (KernelBase.dll) in App.exe: 0x40010004: Debugger terminated process.
Unhandled exception at 0x756C46D2 in App.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Js::JavascriptException at memory location 0x07C9E858.

And also Unchecked Script in  Just in compiler (Debugger Options)